# Randomly choose a hyperlink

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, href

On my blog I have 12 different genres (Music, Photography, Architecture etc...) and then at least 2 different images of each genre on one page. I am currently using smoothscroll.js. When you click on photography (for example) it will currently go straight to the first Hyperlink(X)

```
<a href="#photgraphy"> photography </a>




<a name="photography"> </a> [X]
<a name="photography"> </a> [Y]
```

Is there a way that when you click on photography it chooses **randomly** X or Y instead of it going to the first hyperlink (X).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Create an array of links
            myLinks = new Array;
            myLinks[0] = "#one";
            myLinks[1] = "#two";
            myLinks[2] = "#three";

            // Slide to random link
            $("a.myRandomLink").click(function(){
                randomLink = Math.round(Math.random() * (myLinks.length-1));
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(myLinks[randomLink]).offset().top + "px"},{duration: 500, easing: "swing"});
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" class="myRandomLink">Random link</a><br><br>

    <div id="one" style="width:100%;height:600px;background-color:#550000;"></div>
    <div id="two" style="width:100%;height:600px;background-color:#005500;"></div>
    <div id="three" style="width:100%;height:600px;background-color:#000055;"></div>
    <div id="four" style="width:100%;height:600px;background-color:#ffffff;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user1857312 What you mean? Have you loaded `jQuery` library?

Comment: Yeah. It opens each link in a new tab and goes directly to the link without scrolling. **smoothscroll.js**

Comment: @user1857312 My example just selects one of the links randomly. You haven't mentioned that you want some kind of scrolling. Unfortunately, I haven't been working with **smoothscroll.js**, refer to its documentation.

Comment: I have been looking through the javascript but don't have a clew where to paste your code. This is the link to where smoothscroll.js can be found [link](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/smoothscroll/smoothscroll.js) if you can be bothered. It would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: @user1857312 See updated answer. It doesn't require even third-party library.

Comment: Hi Edward I have 12 different genres (random links) and this code only seems to work when you use one (genre). I have tried copying and pasting it and changing certain bits [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uGSzJ/2/). But it just causes the first set of hyperlinks to work with the 2nd or the other way round. Can you possibly try and explain what I am doing wrong. Thank you